# Compare data of 2 xmls in xslt

Tags: xslt, xslt-1.0

I am new to XSL. Hence please help me with the below.
I have 2 xmls. I have to do the following in XSL transformation.

if Employee/EmployeeInfo/FirstName = EmployeeSegment/EmployeeSummary/GivenName and Employee/EmployeeInfo/LastName = EmployeeSegment/EmployeeSummary/Surname
  employeeId = EmployeeSegment/EmployeeSummary/EmpId

XML1

```
<Employee>
  <EmployeeInfo>
    <FirstName>ABC</FirstName>
    <LastName>DEF</LastName>
  </EmployeeInfo>
</Employee>
```

XML2

```
<EmployeeSegment>
  <EmployeeSummary>
    <EmpId>1234</EmpId>
    <GivenName>ABC</GivenName>
    <Surname>DEF</Surname>
  </EmployeeSummary>
</EmployeeSegment>
```

I have tried the following. It is not working.

```
<xsl:param name="cjEmployeeSegment" select="document('CJ_Response.xml')"/>
<xsl:for-each select="/ns3:Employee/ns3:EmployeeInfo">
  <xsl:variable name="empFirstName">
      <xsl:value-of select="ns1:FirstName"/>
  </xsl:variable>
  <xsl:variable name="empLastName">
      <xsl:value-of select="ns1:LastName"/>
  </xsl:variable>
  <xsl:for-each select="$cjEmployeeSegment/v32:EmployeeSegment/v31:EmployeeSummary">
    <xsl:if test="$empFirstName=v31:GivenName and $empLastName=v31:Surname">
      <ns12:EmployeeIdentifier>
        <ns12:EmployeeID>
          <xsl:value-of select="v31:EmpId"/>
        </ns12:EmployeeID>
      </ns12:EmployeeIdentifier>
    </xsl:if>
  </xsl:for-each>
</xsl:for-each>
```

Comment: Coding tip: replace your way of setting empFirstName by `<xsl:variable name="empFirstName" select="ns1:FirstName"/>`. It's more concise and can be 5 times faster.

Comment: SO tip: never say something "is not working". Say how it fails.

Answer (score 1):

Assuming you are processing the following input:

**XML**

```
<Employee>
  <EmployeeInfo>
    <FirstName>ABC</FirstName>
    <LastName>DEF</LastName>
  </EmployeeInfo>
</Employee>
```

and there is another XML document named `CJ_Response.xml`:

```
<EmployeeSegment>
  <EmployeeSummary>
    <EmpId>1234</EmpId>
    <GivenName>ABC</GivenName>
    <Surname>DEF</Surname>
  </EmployeeSummary>
</EmployeeSegment>
```

you can use the following stylesheet:

**XSLT 1.0**

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" 
xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
<xsl:output method="xml" version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" indent="yes"/>

<xsl:param name="cj_Response" select="document('CJ_Response.xml')"/>

<xsl:template match="/Employee">
    <root>
        <xsl:for-each select="EmployeeInfo">
            <xsl:variable name="lookup" select="$cj_Response/EmployeeSegment/EmployeeSummary[GivenName = current()/FirstName and Surname = current()/LastName]" />
            <xsl:if test="$lookup">
                <EmployeeIdentifier>
                    <EmployeeID>
                        <xsl:value-of select="$lookup/EmpId"/>
                    </EmployeeID>
                </EmployeeIdentifier>
            </xsl:if>
        </xsl:for-each>
    </root>
</xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

to return:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<root>
   <EmployeeIdentifier>
      <EmployeeID>1234</EmployeeID>
   </EmployeeIdentifier>
</root>
```

---

Of course, this will fail miserably if there are two or more employees with the same name.